# How to calculate accumulated sum of query timings?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, benchmarking, timing

I have a sql file running many queries. I want to see the accumualted sum of all queries. I know that if I turn on timing, or call

```
\timing
 query 1;
 query 2;
 query 3;
 ...
 query n;
```

at the beginning of the script, it will start to show time it takes for each query to run. However,  I need to have the accumulate results of all queries, without having to manually add them.

Is there a systematic way? If not, how can I fetch the interim times to throw them in a variable.

Comment: What tool are you using to run your "SQL file"?

Comment: No particular tool, just feeding them to an instance of postgres sql running from the command line. Is there a particular tool designed for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`pg_stat_statements`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) is a good module that provides a means for tracking execution statistics.

1. First, add `pg_stat_statements` to `shared_preload_libraries` in the
   `postgresql.conf` file. To know where this .conf file exists in your
   filesystem, run `show config_file;`

   ```
   shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
   ```
2. Restart Postgres database
3. Create the extension

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
   ```

Now, the module provides a `View`,  **`pg_stat_statements`**, which helps you to analyze various query execution metrics.

Reset the contents of stat collected before running queries.

```
SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset();
```

Now, execute your script file containing queries.

```
\i script_file.sql
```

You may get all the timing statistics of all the queries executed. To get the total time taken, simply run

```
select sum(total_time) from  pg_stat_statements 
    where query !~* 'pg_stat_statements';
```

The time you get is in `milliseconds`, which may be converted to desired format using various `timestamp` related Postgres functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to time the whole script, on linux or mac you can use the `time` utility to launch the script.

The measurement in this case is a bit more than the sum of the raw query times, because it includes some overhead of starting and running the `psql` command. On my system this overhead is around 20ms.

```
$ time psql < script.sql

…

real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.007s
```

The `real` value is the time it took to execute the whole script, including the aforementioned overhead.

---

The approach in this answer is a crude, simple client side way to measure the runtime of the overall script. It is not useful to measure milli-second precision server side execution times. It still might be sufficient for many use-cases.

The solution of Kaushik Nayak is a way more precise method to time executions directly on the server. It also provides much more insight into the execution (eg. query level times).